# SQL Data Sync Agent 2.0 install error system services

Tags: azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database, hyper-v, azure-data-sync

I am trying to install SQL Data Sync Agent 2.0 but I got this install error
[image]

I am running virtual machines with Hyper-V.
I tried in a windows server 2016 and a windows 10. Up to date.
I added the account to log as a windows service.

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed this issue by adding Computer-name in front of the Username.

Make sure the following,

1. Username and password are correct.
2. Prefix the computer name along with the username (Eg: MYPC\user).

You can find the computer name on **This PC's** properties.

Comment: Thanks for your simple answer.  I thought I had already tried everything, but you were correct - I forgot to include the computer name as the domain for the user.

Comment: As well as in the SQL Data Sync installer, I also had to re-add the account to the "Login as a service" policy (see @Alberto Morillo 's answer below), using the PC-NAME\AccountName format too

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs in two situations:

1. User name and/or password are incorrect. Do not use the Windows Live login to install the agent use (create) a local Windows account to install the agent.
2. The specified user account does not have sufficient privileges to logon as a service, but you told us you did this already. Anyway please verify the following steps:

To Grant logon-as-a-service credentials to the user account please do the following steps:

1. Navigate to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy > Local Policy > User Rights Management.
2. Find and click the Logon as a service entry.
3. Add the user account in the Logon as a service Properties dialog.
4. Click Apply then OK.
5. Close the windows.

Some more suggestions:

Install the client agent using the least privilege account with network service access.

It is best if the client agent is installed on a computer separate from your on premises SQL Server computer.

Comment: So I have to "create a local Windows account to install the agent.". This product looks half baked to me.

Comment: No it is not. It started in preview back in 2010 and it was put on GA 2018.  Very stable and very reliable.