# SQL Data Sync Agent pre-installation error "verify you have sufficient privileges"

Tags: synchronization, azure-sql-database

I have seen this question: [SQL Data Sync Agent 2.0 install error system services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62023611/sql-data-sync-agent-2-0-install-error-system-services) but it does not account for what the password is.

Trying to install Sql Data Sync Agent to connect an on-prem sql db to an Azure sql db. My on-prem sql db is in the same computer as where I am installing the agent.

Before installation, the agent tool requires a user name and password. I've ensured that the user name input is this computer's DOMAIN\User and that the user is in "Log on as a service" in the Local Security Policy, however I am not sure what the password could be since I do not use a password to log into this computer. So I leave the password blank when Sql Data Sync Agent asks for it and I get the "verify you have sufficient privileges" error. I'm not sure what to do.

I've tried continuing the installation without a password and with the default 'sa' password. I've tried using my Microsoft account user name and password, but the agent tool requires a DOMAIN\User for the user name.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install the SQL agent I got the same error:

[image]

I added the `NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES`  in log an as service in local policies

[image]

It resolved the issue. For more informarion you can refer[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/azure-ad-hybrid-sync-no-privileges-install-msi).